# Regex to match the string "Hello, name"

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I need a regex which can match "Hello, name" pattern but the comma is optional. If the comma is not present, the number of spaces between Hello and name should be one. If the comma is present, then the number of spaces between comma and name should be one. After Hello + (comma+space or space), there should at least be one character and after that anything can follow

I tried the following regex

```
Hello,?\s{1}\S.*
```

But it also matches `"Hello , name"` i.e space between Hello and comma.

Comment: And, what is your problem with this regex?  (see: https://regex101.com/r/EJgZTm/1 ), it seems to be working fine...

Comment: This regex will also accept this -> "Hello , name" i.e space between Hello and comma

Comment: What prevents you from using the alternation you verbalized in your question: `Hello(?:, | )\w+`?

Answer (score 4):

The reason `Hello,?\s{1}\S.*` matches `"Hello , name"` (space after Hello) is:

- `Hello` matches the initial `"Hello"`.
- Since the comma is optional, it is not matched
- `\s{1}` matches the space after the `"Hello"` (Note the `{1}` is redundant. `\s` on its own will do the same thing, match a single whitespace)
- `\S` matches the comma
- `.*` matches the rest of the string, i.e. `" name"`

To prevent this, consider disallowing commas and spaces in the name with the following regex: `^Hello,?\s[^,\s]+$` [Try online](https://regex101.com/r/lFvJCS/1):

```
^Hello,?\s[^,\s]+$
------------------
^                $      : Start and end of string
 Hello                  : Literal Hello
      ,?                : Optional comma
        \s              : One whitespace
          [^,\s]+       : One or more characters that are not comma or space
```

```
import re

strings = """Hello, Chopin
Hello Brahms
Hello,  Mozart
Hello , name
Hello  name
Hello Chopin""".split("\n")

for test in strings:
    print(test, re.search(r"^Hello,?\s[^,\s]+$", test))
```

gives:

```
Hello, Chopin <re.Match object; span=(0, 13), match='Hello, Chopin'>
Hello Brahms <re.Match object; span=(0, 12), match='Hello Brahms'>
Hello,  Mozart None
Hello , name None
Hello  name None
Hello Chopin <re.Match object; span=(0, 12), match='Hello Chopin'>
```

Comment: The thing is ,first letter of the name can be anything...can also start with comma

Comment: Of course! Here we fall into the old [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). In that case, would `", name"` not be a valid name? And the message `"Hello , name"` would be a valid message

Comment: Warning to those quick readers.... The `Try online` version is using a different regex, than the regex at the start of this answer. (Just to much , so i wasted 15 minutes )

Comment: The regex at the start of the answer is also not the regex that this answer is recommending. I'm making it clearer so people reading this drunk on future New Years eves won't be confused @Luuk :D

Comment: @Chopin in continuation to my comment above from yesterday, what are the criteria for deciding if something is allowable as a name? If it can contain commas and spaces, then `"Hello , name"` is a valid input (name=`", name"`). If commas are allowed but not spaces, you can change the regex to remove the comma from `[^,\s]+`

Answer (score 3):

You could use a  [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to prevent `,` getting matched from `\S`.

```
Hello,?\s(?!,)\S.*
```

[See the demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Kbyh6q/1) - To allow `Hello ,name` use [`Hello,?\s(?!,\s)\S.*`](https://regex101.com/r/AIKXMU/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex, `Hello,?\s\S.*` which can be explained as follows:

- `Hello`: The word, Hello
- `,?`: Optional comma
- `\s`: Single whitespace character
- `\S`: Single non-space character
- `.*`: Any character any number of times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tXPAON/1)

Comment: This runs into the same problem OP originally reported: `"Hello , name"` is matched.

Answer (score -2):

This regular expression will match the string "Hello, name" even if there are other characters before or after it.

```
import re

pattern = r".*Hello, name.*"

# Test the regular expression
if re.match(pattern, "Hello, name"):
    print("Match found!")
else:
    print("Match not found.")
```

Comment: While your explanation matches your pattern, it is unfortunately not an answer to the question. (not my downvote btw)